# Alignment issue with Chart JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm looking for a solution for this problem I'm facing with Angular ChartJs [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCETX.png)

I got no idea how to post up my code online but the parts to my code is screen shot-ed:

JS:

```
angular.module('piMonitorClientApp')
  .controller('GraphCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $http, $timeout) {
console.log("Graph page log")

$scope.labels = [];


$scope.tempLabels = [];
$scope.temperatureData = [];
$scope.temperatureArray = [];
$scope.temperatureSeries = ['Temperature'];

$scope.varLabels = [];
$scope.varData = [];
$scope.varArray = [];
$scope.varSeries = ['var'];

$scope.ldrLabels = [];
$scope.ldrData = [];
$scope.ldrArray=[];
$scope.ldrSeries = ['ldr'];


$http.get("http://localhost:9001/getData")
  .success(function(response) {
    $scope.obj = response;

    angular.forEach($scope.obj, function(value) {
      if($scope.labels.indexOf(value.id) === -1) {

        $scope.tempLabels.push(value.date);
        $scope.temperatureArray.push(value.temperature);

        $scope.varLabels.push(value.date);
        $scope.varArray.push(value.var_resistor);

        $scope.ldrLabels.push(value.date);
        $scope.ldrArray.push(value.ldr);
      }
    });
  });
$scope.varData.push($scope.varArray);
$scope.temperatureData.push($scope.temperatureArray);
$scope.ldrData.push($scope.ldrArray);
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="well well-lg">
    <canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-    data="temperatureData"
                                chart-labels="tempLabels" chart-series="temperatureSeries" chart-options="options"
                                chart-click="onClick">
</canvas>
```

```
  var_resistor
<div class="well well-lg">
  <canvas id="line2" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="varData"
          chart-labels="varLabels" chart-series="varSeries" chart-options="options"
          chart-click="onClick">
  </canvas>
</div>

ldr
  <div class="well well-lg">
    <canvas id="line3" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="ldrData"
            chart-labels="ldrLabels" chart-series="ldrSeries" chart-options="options"
            chart-click="onClick">
    </canvas>
  </div>
```

Still rather new to AngularJs and ChartJS so hopefully someone out there can tell me why is the alignment wrong other than my temperature graph. All help is appreciated!

Comment: May be it's aligned by depend of the data